# Standing Generalizations of the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I remember reading that Erdös once that mathematics isn't mature enough to tackle the Collatz conjecture. However, the Collatz conjecture seems like a rather specific problem to me.

Are there any standing generalizations of the Collatz conjecture? Is work being done to prove the generalization?

Regards.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but, really, why not just type *Collatz generalization* into a search engine to see what comes up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and yes. Jeff Lagarias published a book collecting together many of the most important papers on Collatz and generalizations, and I recommend this book to anyone interested in these problems.

Comment: Thanks, that book seems really interesting, unfortunately I don't have access to it.

Comment: Do you not have access to a library?

Comment: Yes, I do. But they mostly have business stuff.

Comment: Sure. But do they do interlibrary loan?

Comment: Yes, but only with other libraries from the business school I go to. They don't have that book, along with many others I've been meaning to read.

Comment: Do you have access to a public library that does interlibrary loan?

Comment: No, I don't, but I might be able to find it online.

Comment: Yes, I found it in a chinese website, all I need to do is register.

Comment: Nevermind, it turned out to be a summary